# Best way to select parameters to SARIMAX model

Tags: time-series, arima

I am trying to understand what is the best way to find the hyper-parameters for an SARIMAX timeseries model, this has 4 additional parameters (P-AR parameters,D-differences,Q-MA parameters,s-periodicity) on top of the three (p-AR parameters,d-differences,q-MA parameters) that are in ARMIA. Are there any practical suggestions on how to set those?

Note: I am using the python statsmodels implementation of SARIMAX

Comment: The idea should be very similar to that of determining the parameters $p$, $d$, $q$ of the regular ARIMA model, except for periodicity $s$ which is often known and is supplied manually by the user. Also, I would not call the $P$, $D$, $Q$ and $S$ "hyperparameters" as they are as much "hyper" as the $p$, $d$ and $q$ are.

Comment: What is a hyper parameter? Can you explain?